# How to identify if tweet is original or retweet in scraping with HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, filter, html-agility-pack, tweets

I wanted Twitter tweets of user for data analysis. For that I have used [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/web-scraping-in-c-sharp/) package to scrape Twitter and it gives me 30 top tweets.

I recognized tweet-text element and fetched all tweets. But I want to identify if it is tweet or retweet. How can I do that?

I have analysed HTML. In retweet there will be an element having `tweet-context with-icn` class. But when I scrape tweet on that class it throws null exception, because not all tweets will have that class. Then based on what and how can I scrape to get to know if it is retweet or not?

Code:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://twitter.com/BarackObama");

var TweetsNode= doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='tweet-container']").ToList();

foreach (var item in TweetsNode)
{
    var tweet = new Tweets
    {
        console.WriteLine(item.innertext);
    };
}
```

In the above code, I have tried to fetch tweets of Barack Obama profile. I'm getting top 30 tweets. How can I recognize which one is retweet?
Thank you.

Comment: It seems you already answered your own question in paragraph 2 with your own paragraph 3. Can you specify what your exact problem is?

Comment: What do you want as a result? A List Object with 30 Tweets and each has a flag `IsRetweet` ?  

Comment: i  am getting tweet text. i want to know it is tweet or retweet? if i try to fetch based on retweet text class. than it will thow null exception.because. not in every tweet that class will be present. so bsed on what and how i can filter that.is it retweet?

Comment: @Smartis yes.exactly that.

Comment: It is a "without code" question. Tell us what you've tried so far and where you got stuck. You've already indicated that you're able to scrape tweets in general, so you just need to find something that makes a retweet unique (e.g. the `js-retweet-text`) class. Frankly you should show the code you already have tried already.

Comment: @john check my edit. i mentioned that i tried to csrap data with retweet element name.but that will throw exception because not all tweets will have that. so what other i can do m seeking help for that.

Comment: `var isRetweet = tweet.Descendants().Any(d => d.HasClass("js-retweet-text"));` works just fine for me. See, this is the problem. This is why your question is bad. You have code, but you won't show it. I 100% guarantee that you would already have an answer tailored to your code now if you had posted it.

Comment: no.dear.not at all..why should i waste my time in posting question if i have answer..its just i didnt gettign what should i post in code.trust me.its not roket science code which i made and i wanted to hide it.

Comment: Including code almost always makes it more clear what you're trying to accomplish and might even allow us to, oh I don't know, try it out for ourselves and help find a solution.

Comment: @john sorry john. i stil didnt get you.what is tweet here? list of tweets that i get? pls check my edit.i have updated code :D

Comment: @DanWilson updated question with code.

Comment: @Neelam it's equivalent to your "item".

Comment: @john thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Scraping Twitter 101

1. Get all Tweets from a page (which comes in handy tables `<table class='tweet  '>`)

   ```
   HtmlWeb p = new HtmlWeb();
   var doc = p.Load(@"https://twitter.com/dailygametips");
   var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='tweet  ']");
   ```
2. Look in nodes for the `<span class='context'>` to indicated that this tweet is a retweet.

   ```
   List<Tweet> tweets = new List<Tweet>();
   foreach (var node in nodes)
   {
       bool isRetweet = false;
       var spanNode = node.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='context']");
       if (spanNode != null && spanNode.InnerHtml.Contains("retweeted"))
       {
           isRetweet = true;
       }
   ```
3. We also want the Message Text, so scrap this next `<div class='tweet-text'>`:

   ```
       string msg = string.Empty;
       var msgNode = node.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='tweet-text']");
       if (msgNode != null)
       {
           msg = msgNode.InnerText.Trim();
       }
       tweets.Add(new Tweet(msg, isRetweet));
   }
   ```

---

Additional the Tweet Container Class:

```
class Tweet
{
    public Tweet(string message, bool isRetweet)
    {
        Message = message;
        IsRetweet = isRetweet;
    }

    string Message { get; private set; }
    bool IsRetweet { get; private set; }
}
```

---

As you tell, this is not really rocket science. But you need to understand the basic principals of XPath and Scrapping.

Comment: oh...man..thank you soooooooooooooo much. what i was doing is wrong traversing of  html i think.. thank you for your specific and clear answer. although my question was so confusing.. :) i owe you ..

Comment: @Smarties can u suggest me any good link for understand better Xpath and scrapping. i need to scrape some other fileds also. so i want to try it by my self.

Comment: and another question i dont get fully parsed html in this.so some elements which i can see in html source code i cant find that in parsed code using HTMLAligibillity pack. in our case "doc" what should i do for that?

Comment: @NeelamPrajapati Send you a Repo Link fia Twitter